# Can "dissolute" be plural?

Tags: word-usage, nouns, grammatical-number

I have a text I'm proofreading that lists certain types of people, and in the list is the word "dissolutes" ("highwaymen, loners, children, dissolutes"). My Word processor is telling me that while "dissolute" is fine, "dissolutes" is not an acceptable word.  Help?

ps. this is a made up list of adjectives used to represent the type of list I'm dealing with, not the real thing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear. We have no idea what actual word you wish to pluralize, other than you think it is an adjective (whch would not vary in the plural). On the other hand, you also appear to think *children* an adjective, so ???

Comment: My Collins English Dictionary only lists *dissolute* as being an adjective, so there is no plural.  That said, I would understand *dissolutes* to mean *people who are dissolute*.

Comment: Your word processor is not the final word on English.  Have you tried looking it up?  Also,  what you have is a list of nouns.  Your question really is:  Can dissolute be used as a noun, and in the plural?

Comment: Yeah, no word processor's "opinion" as to spelling and grammar should ever be taken as more than a "suggestion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, dissolute is an adjective, and for this reason cannot have a plural.  Only nouns can have a plural. This is why the word processor doesn't accept it.

However adjectives applied to people are sometimes used as nouns, and in the example given, it is clear that that is meant. Many people would feel it is acceptable to use dissolute, or dissolutes, as short for dissolute person, or dissolute people. If you do not care about using formal English, in the particular context, then you could use dissolutes, and people would understand you.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Oxford English Dictionary attests the noun *dissolute* in this meaning, and has examples of the plural form *dissolutes,* but notes that it is "rare," and the most recent example is from 1838.

Answer (score 1):

The sources I consulted (Etomoline; Webster's New Collegiate, Merriam Webster) say ***dissolute*** is an adjective, but I found one example of ***dissolute*** used as a noun:

> At least, first take out of it the drunkard and the dissolute of your
>   own Church.

this is from [Charles Bradlaugh: a Record of His Life and Work, Volume 2 (of 2) by Bonner et al](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/45131?msg=welcome_stranger), as quoted in [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dissolute)

Thus, if I wanted to use *dissolutes* as a plural noun, I would.  But it is not clear from your question how you want to use it.  I certainly would not pair it with loners and children.

As an example, just add an *s* to *drunkard* and to *dissolute* in the sentence quoted above.

Answer (score 1):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) doesn't have an entry for *dissolute* as a noun, which indicates that the word is not (as of 2003) in common parlance in English as a noun, in the United States or elsewhere. *Webster's Third New International Dictionary* (1961/1986)—the big Merriam-Webster dictionary—doesn't have an entry for it either, suggesting that, as a noun, the word (as of 1986) was not in recognized active use at a significant level anywhere.

*The Compact Edition of the Oxford English Dictionary* (1971/1985), however, offers this definition:

> **Dissolute** ... B. *sb.* A dissolute person, a profligate. *rare*.

The *OED* entry then cites instances of noun use of *dissolute* by John Day (in 1608), Walter Savage Landor (in 1824), and Robert Southey (in 1838). The upshot of these resources' treatment of *dissolute* as a noun is that the word is quite unusual in that role, but that its meaning is pretty much what you might expect, given the meaning of the common adjective form of the word.

Answer (score 0):

dissolute is an adjective, can not use as a noun. So there isn't plural form of "dissolute", add a noun, like dissolute people.